# How to correctly implement callbacks using dagger for dependency injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, callback, dagger

I'm using the Mapzen Lost api for location services, dagger for dependency injection and retrofit to get weather data for the device's current location. I'm having an issue with trying to create a callback from the lostLocationService so that the retrofit request doesn't get sent until it's confirmed that a location has been found.

My issue is with dependencies. I have a Presenter which has a dependency of a LocationService and that has a dependency of a LostLocationService. 
I have a location listener in my LostLocationService class in which I override onLocationChanged()

```
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        myLocationListener.onLocationFound();
    }
};
```

This all seems fine but only exposes the callback to the LostLocationService. Do I need a callback for each level of dependency? Or more likely, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I was also wondering whether listeners should be injected or not and what was the easiest way to deal with them.

In your case, maybe you should consider using a List of listener (if possible) to dispatch the events to all the concerned instances. This works well if every listener has a well defined life-cycle and can register/unregister predictively. This way, you could avoid having some "cascades" of listeners.

I don't know the details of your implementation, but I guess that here your LocationService serves as an abstraction layer ? I that's the case, I would do this:

- Define a LocationService with a dependency on LostLocationService. The LocationService will handle all the details of the LostLocationService.
- The LocationService listens to the events reported by the LostLocationService.
- The LocationService has a List of listeners that grows dynamically (you can add and remove them).
- The LocationService reports the main events to all its listeners when it's needed.

I would also use some interfaces here, as it will be easier to change your code / test it later. Define a LocationProviderInterface that exposes some utility functions (startService, stopService, addListener, etc...). Also, define an interface that the listeners should implement (as you have already done it seems).

Also, don't hesitate to elaborate on your first point.

> I'm having an issue with trying to create a callback from the
>   lostLocationService so that the retrofit request doesn't get sent
>   until it's confirmed that a location has been found.

Comment: Thanks for this @Gordak. I've been off the project for a while so have only just seen your reply.

Comment: You're correct about the LocationService serving as an abstraction layer. I think you're also right about the LocationService needing to listen for the callback from the LostLocationService. Yes I already have a listener interface and the others are a nice idea :-)  To elaborate on my initial point:- I have the callback setup but get a null object reference when I try to respondWithLocationFound. I think this is due to dependencies and trying to do so from the presenter (which doesn't have access to the callback). I'll implement the second level of listeners and come back with my findings.